# Refresh TableView except pull to refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I use Parse to save data and every time I add new data to server,TableView doesn't refresh and get new data

Is any way to refresh TableView except pull refresh ?

Comment: only workaround is to use push notification to send update of data which will get out of proportion as number of users grow. You might want to switch to Firebase now - that will solve this for you

Comment: Use timer to call data from server and reload tableView after new data come.

Answer (score 2):

First of all Add Observer method which will notify when you.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("ReloadTableData"), object: nil)
```

**Register that observer method in your view controller on which tableview you used.**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("ReloadTableData"), object: nil)
```

and create one function and reload your tableview

This might by your possible solutions for reloading without pull to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Whenever the user get back to the app or opens the app.
You can add in in the method

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

If the user is still in the app while the updates are being performed, then use push notification. In the method

```
appDidReceiveRemoteNotification
```

reload the data. You have to register for remote notification and all the process before you receive any push notification, but that is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

first of all Adding refresh control to the tableview. So add the below code in `ViewDidLoad`.

```
    let refresh = UIRefreshControl()
    refresh.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string:"Loading..!!", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
    refresh.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresh)
    self.tableView.sendSubviewToBack(refresh)
```

Now Calling the method when you Pull-To-refresh Tableview.

```
func handleRefresh(refreshControl : UIRefreshControl){
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

**Refresh Control :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implement a push notification or use LiveQuery on [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server).

[LiveQuery](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-LiveQuery) allows you to subscribe to a Parse.Query you are interested in. Once subscribed, the server will notify clients whenever a Parse.Object that matches the Parse.Query is created or updated, in real-time.

LiveQuery is already support [IOS](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX).

for more detail see the hyperLink.

- https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server
- https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-LiveQuery
- https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX